# Send data with serial port

Tags: c#

I want to program a rolling base. The connection of TX, RX, and GND of the base is with rs232, but I haven't this port on my laptop. So I'm using an adaptor USB-RS232. The connection works because when I enter the different commands in Putty, the robot moves. 
So in visual studio, I create a serial port with this line :

```
SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM7", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
```

After, I connect it:

```
try
{
    serialPort1.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please connect to the base");
}
```

So the serial port is opened. And finally, I send the buffer :

```
if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
{
    string str = "!m 1 300";
    serialPort1.Write(str);
    System.Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

But it doesn't work, the robot doesn't move. In Putty I enter the same command:

```
!m 1 300
```

Maybe I forget something?

Comment: You're writing to the Console? Did you mean to write to serialPort?

Comment: Does the robot have a more basic command like a ping or status type command you could try to verify that your serial communication is working?  What is the robot?  What is the protocol you are trying to use?   You probably just need to send a CR or some kind of end-of-line sequence. Like maybe:  `"!m 1 300\n"`  (Or use `serialPort1.WriteLine` to accomplish the same thing)

Comment: Do you need to press _Enter_ after entering `!m 1 300` when you use **Putty** to get the robot to move?  If so, then that will confirm you need to send an end-of-line sequence as I described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be more appropriate to use serialPort1.Write(string).
If you use serialPort1.WriteLine(string) it will send a newline character after the string, which may not be expected by the device on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing to the console instead of the serial port. Try this:

```
if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
{
    string str = "!m 1 300";
    serialPort1.Write(str);
}
```

You should also be aware of the [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=netframework-4.8) and know that the default encoding it uses is ASCII encoding.